# Explain behavior of Unix sleep() function executed on Android

Tags: android, c++, linux, cross-compiling, sleep

I am currently compiling and executing some C++ code on a rooted Android device. I use adb (adb shell). To compile my code, I don't use the NDK, but I cross-compile with CMake

I'm using the function [`sleep(seconds)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) of unistd.h.

I've experienced some curious behaviors with that function on Android: Basically, I have a for loop in which I std::cout something and then call `sleep(x)`.

If I call `sleep(1)`, the behavior is the one expected: The program waits 1 second, and then executes the next instructions.

If I call `sleep(2)`, the behavior isn't the one expected. The program gets stuck on that instruction for ever.... until I hit a key on my PC keyboard (not the device's one), and then it gets stuck on the next `sleep(2)`... until I hit a key, etc...

This behavior happens only when the device screen is off. As soon as I click on the power button to turn the screen on, the program resumes and has the expected behavior.

N.B: The behavior is the same with [`usleep(useconds)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep)

I have tried to see where the limit is between 1 and 2 seconds:
1.5s, 1.25s, 1.125s -> always stay blocked | 1.0625s -> ~50% chance of staying blocked.

Obviously, there is something that prevents a thread to wake up if it sleeps more than 1 seconds (at least 2).
So my question would be, does anyone have any idea of why this is happening, and has a detailed explanation of the process ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Android puts applications in the background when they aren't doing any user interaction - unix sleep and java timers etc. won't wake them up.  You have to use an android alarm or runnable postDelayed handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! do you have any documentation that specifies that, and give more details ? (for example on the time threshold for which the process in stopped by Android)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html  See item 4. "A background process ... the system can kill such processes at any time ..."  It is vague, but empirically, I rember seeing this happen consistently on older androids (before jelly bean) after about 5 secs.  I haven't tested newer ones.